# Newline being ignored in email

Tags: php

I am building an email, just a simple text one. Part of the email is from CSV file and I want to have a newline `\n` after each entry. For some reason this is ignored. I am replaceing the comma as follows.

```
 $orderDetails = str_replace(',', '\n\n', $orderDetails);
```

Then it is added in the email

```
$email_body = "Hello Joe Bloggs, \n\n Below are the order details \n\n".$orderDetails;
```

For some reason the received email prints the `\n\n` rather than actually putting a new line. So the email actually looks like

```
  Hello Joe blogs 


  Below are the order details


  item 1\n\nitem 2\n\nitem 3\n\n
```

Why is this?

Comment: please show what is in $orderDetails

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use double-quotes in the `str_replace()`:

```
$orderDetails = str_replace(',', "\n\n", $orderDetails);
```

Inside double-quotes, PHP wil interpret `\n` as a special character. See [PHP Strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

Answer (score 0):

Use `\r\n` and the double quotes.

```
$orderDetails = str_replace(',', "\r\n", $orderDetails);
```